# Getting the value of the second selectbox to fetch result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch city,county,area in a nested select for my project.
So I have 3 levels of nested selects. But when I try to fetch the data with 2 variables, I cannot pass the value of "first selected select" to the fetch url.

How can I pass the value of firstly selected select value to the fetch url?

I need to replace **this.MUSTBEVALUEOFTHESECONDSELECTEDSELECT** with the value

Here is a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/krsj3ecy/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {


    var app = new Vue({
      el: '.app',
      name: "IlIlceUygulaması",
      data: {

        iller: {},
        ilceler: {},
        mahalleler: {},

        selected: 0,
        ilSecildi: false,
        ilceSecildi: false,



      },


      methods: {
        illeriGetir() {
          fetch("https://www.example.com/loc/")
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
              this.iller = result;
            })
        },
        ilceleriGetir() {
          this.ilSecildi = true;
          fetch(`https://www.example.com/loc/${this.selected}`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
              this.ilceler = result;
            })
        },
        mahalleleriGetir() {
          this.ilSecildi = true;
          this.ilceSecildi = true;

          fetch(`https://www.example.com/loc/${this.MUSTBEVALUEOFTHESECONDSELECTEDSELECT}/${this.selected}`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
              this.mahalleler = result;
            })
        }
      }
    })
    app.illeriGetir();
  });

</script>


<div class="app" style="margin-top:50px">
  <b>İl Seçiniz</b>
  <select class="form-control col-md-3" v-model="selected" v-on:change="ilceleriGetir()">

                                    <option v-for="list in iller"
                                            v-bind:value="list.cityid">
                                        {{list.cityname}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
  <div v-if="ilSecildi" style="margin-top:50px">
    <b> İlçe Seçiniz</b>
    <select class="form-control col-md-3" v-on:change="mahalleleriGetir()">
                                        <option v-for="list in ilceler"
                                                v-bind:value="list.countyid">
                                            {{list.countyname}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
  </div>

  <div v-if="ilceSecildi" style="margin-top:50px">
    <b> Mahalle Seçiniz</b>
    <select class="form-control col-md-3">
                                        <option v-for="list in mahalleler"
                                                v-bind:value="list.areaid">
                                            {{list.areaname}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Isn't `this.selected` the value of the first select?

Comment: You are right, I have to get value of the second selection. I am mistaken.

Comment: create a variable for each of them to `v-model` like you did for the first one. Maybe `selected2` and `selected3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new object that has properties for each select box to mutate:

```
selections: {
    iller: null,
    ilceler: null,
    mahalleler: null
}
```

Update all your `v-model` bindings:

```
v-model="selections.iller"
v-model="selections.ilceler"
v-model="selections.mhalleler"
```

Now you can get them correctly.